# Filter numeric column by dictionary of value ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a dictionary:

```
df = 

VARIABLE VALUE
A        3
A        4
A        60
A        5
B        1
B        2
B        3
B        100
C        0
C        1
```

```py
# inclusive
accepted_ranges={
A:[3,5],
B:[1,3]
}
```

And I would like to clean the VALUE column according to the accepted ranges in the dictionary.

```
df = 

VARIABLE VALUE
A        3
A        4
A        NaN
A        5
B        1
B        2
B        3
B        NaN
C        0
C        1
```

I have tried: using `map()` but I can't seem to find a way to use it by VARIABLE groups. `apply()` would work, I think, however, `apply()` works really slow with my dataframe (>10M rows). Thank you beforehand.

Comment: With 10M rows, about how many unique entries do you have in the dict?

Comment: @ALollz Around 50

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map your dictionary to each `VARIABLE`. Then we use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to check if each `VALUE` is between the range.

Finally we use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to convert the `False` values to `NaN`

```
ranges = df['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges)
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].where(df['VALUE'].between(ranges.str[0], ranges.str[1]))

  VARIABLE  VALUE
0        A    3.0
1        A    4.0
2        A    NaN
3        A    5.0
4        B    1.0
5        B    2.0
6        B    3.0
7        B    NaN
8        C    0.0
9        C    1.0
```

---

#### More speed!

The `.str` accessor can be quite slow and are mostly "loopy" implementations on the background. Especially since you have ~10m rows in your data, this can cause for less efficient code. We can solve this by splitting your `accepted_ranges` in two dictionarys and thus create two vectors with `Series.map`:

```
accepted_ranges1 = {k: v[0] for k, v in accepted_ranges.items()}
accepted_ranges2 = {k: v[1] for k, v in accepted_ranges.items()}

ranges1 = df['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges1)
ranges2 = df['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges2)

m1 = df['VALUE'].between(ranges1, ranges2)
m2 = ~df['VARIABLE'].isin(list(accepted_ranges.keys()))

df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].where(m1|m2)
```

---

#### Speed comparison

```
# create example dataframe of 10m rows
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*1000000, ignore_index=True)
dfbig.shape

# (10000000, 2)
```

```
# Erfan 1
%%timeit
ranges = dfbig['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges)
dfbig['VALUE'].where(dfbig['VALUE'].between(ranges.str[0], ranges.str[1]))

10 s ± 466 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# Erfan 2
%%timeit
accepted_ranges1 = {k: v[0] for k, v in accepted_ranges.items()}
accepted_ranges2 = {k: v[1] for k, v in accepted_ranges.items()}

ranges1 = dfbig['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges1)
ranges2 = dfbig['VARIABLE'].map(accepted_ranges2)

dfbig['VALUE'].where(dfbig['VALUE'].between(ranges1, ranges2))

1.03 s ± 22.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# piRSquared
%%timeit
mask = [
    accepted_ranges[k][0] <= v <= accepted_ranges[k][1]
    for k, v in zip(dfbig.VARIABLE, dfbig.VALUE)
]

dfbig.VALUE.where(mask)

3.11 s ± 106 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: The ranges are inclusive in both ends. 
Should I still use between()?

Comment: Yes, if look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), you can see that the method is by default inclusive.

Comment: See edit for a method which should be faster @Kaisar

Comment: Hey, would you mind checking a change I just made? I took the 'C' key out of the dictionary and now all the values for 'C' are dissapearing after using the first method in your answer with between() and where()
.

Comment: See edit at "more speed" solution. We check for presence of variables in dictionary @Kaisar

Answer (score 6):

#### boolean mask

```
mask = [
    accepted_ranges[k][0] <= v <= accepted_ranges[k][1]
    for k, v in zip(df.VARIABLE, df.VALUE)
]

df[mask]

  VARIABLE  VALUE
0        A      3
1        A      4
3        A      5
4        B      1
5        B      2
6        B      3
8        C      0
9        C      1
```

OR

```
df.assign(VALUE=df.VALUE.where(mask))

  VARIABLE  VALUE
0        A    3.0
1        A    4.0
2        A    NaN
3        A    5.0
4        B    1.0
5        B    2.0
6        B    3.0
7        B    NaN
8        C    0.0
9        C    1.0
```

Comment: df[mask] gives me a different result. df.assign() works.

Comment: `df[mask]` subsets the dataframe.  `df.assign` is overwriting the column with the results of `df.where`.  `df.where` is keeping the values where the mask is `True` and making the others `np.nan`